# modifications done in jsp page are not showing effects in project

Tags: javascript, jsp, myeclipse

in one of my jsp page button i kept validation using javascript, i kept code like:

```
alert("hai");
```

and i built my project, i got `"hai"` whenever the page is submitted.

later i changed the code in javascript to :

```
alert("hello");
```

and i have run the project, but im not getting `"hello"`, instead of it im getting hia i.e previously written code.

im using myeclipse 8.6.
i thought its project file buildng problem n i have rebuilt it manually,
but no result.

any help please

Comment: please elaborate you question as it doesn't give a clear understanding of what problem you are facing

Comment: how to clear cache...im new to myeclipse and all..

Comment: i have clean the project(project-->clean) and rebuilt the project...but it doesnt

Comment: Redeploy application, restart server, refresh browser.

Comment: hi paulius,,got it now...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with Server..
restart server and run app...

if it still happen,,then go with new server